# Как создать таблицу в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я новичок в мире python.
Мне нужно загрузить данные из таблицы excel к себе в программу. Для работы с excel буду использовать xlrd. Не хотел уходить далеко в дебри и хочу делать интерфейс стандартными средства, и, как я понимаю, "встроенным" инструментом тут выступает tkinter.
Как мне создать таблицу с ним? Или все-таки лучше обратиться к сторонним библиотекам (к примеру, к PyQT)?

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: *"Мне нужно загрузить данные из таблицы excel к себе в программу."* не требует создания GUI таблицы. Достаточно, xlrd, чтобы достать данные из .xls и .xlsx файлов.

Comment: Хочу отображать таблицы excel в своей программе. Хочу, чтобы сотрудники нашего учреждения делали изменения данных непосредственно из программы.

Comment: Можно наизнанку вывернуть: редактировать Excel файлы в самом Excel и [вызывать из Экселя необходимые функции Питона, например, c помощью xlwings](http://xlwings.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать `Treeview()`.

Есть один кусочек кода, который получает кортежи из таблицы sqlite и создает таблицу.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, headings=tuple(), rows=tuple()):
        super().__init__(parent)

        table = ttk.Treeview(self, show="headings", selectmode="browse")
        table["columns"]=headings
        table["displaycolumns"]=headings

        for head in headings:
            table.heading(head, text=head, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            table.column(head, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for row in rows:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=tuple(row))

        scrolltable = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=table.yview)
        table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrolltable.set)
        scrolltable.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)


root = tk.Tk()
table = Table(root, headings=('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), rows=((123, 456, 789), ('abc', 'def', 'ghk')))
table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

В tkinter нет встроенного модуля для работы с таблицами.

Comment: Существует [tktable расширение tcl/tk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/), которое содержит пример [tktable.py](http://tktable.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tktable/tktable/library/tktable.py?view=markup).

Answer (score -1):

Насколько помню, я встречал библиотеку для работы с Excel-файлами в python. Но отображение такого файла в Tkinter подходящими средствами напрямую не выйдет (нет такого виджета).

Придется изобретать такой элемент, либо использовать имеющиеся наработки, что часто бывает проще.

Answer (score -2):

попробуй просто метод `.grid()`
[https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/Курс_по_библиотеке_Tkinter_языка_Python](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.